# How to use Lambda so the if statement is it's own test condition without rewriting if statement in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

This is a general question based not on specific formula - but I couldn't find an answer to it anywhere - but it seems like it should be possible.
In this screenshot, you, Y and X are the same for the sake of example (there is a slight difference, but for example's sake - let's assume it's the same).
[image]

In the formula, the same formula is used in an if statement to determine if we should move forward with actually calculating the formula. Is there a way to use lambda not to repeat the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you may condense it to something in the sorts of:

```
=lambda(X,if(X>0,X,0))(*FORMULA*)
```

a generalized example in the screenshot:

[image]